# What does the "motive is not type correct" error mean in Lean?

Tags: lean, lean3

Sometimes, trying to use `rw` in Lean, we get an error saying

```
motive is not type correct
```

What does this mean? Often `simp_rw` succeeds, so what we want to rewrite can be rewritten and the end: why `rw` is not enough?

Comment: Have you tried searching in the [Zulip chat](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/)? It already contains a lot of helpful info. But it's worth discussing whether we should also have some of the answers here though.

Comment: Yes, there are several explanation on Zulip. I feel it is worth to also have one here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This tends to show up when trying to rewrite a term that appears as a dependent argument.

---

To understand this, let’s see how `rw` actually works, by way of a small example:

I’m using [`list.last`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/data/list/basic.html#list.last) with type

```
list.last {α : Type u} (l : list α) : l ≠ list.nil → α
```

as an example for a function with a dependent argument: The second argument is a proof that mentions the first argument `l`.

Let’s try to prove the following lemma:

```
open list

example (α : Type*) (l : list α) (h1 : l ≠ nil) (x : α) (hx : l = [x]) :
  last l h1 = x :=
begin
```

We might want to start to rewrite with that equality, but

```
  rw hx,
```

fails with

```
rewrite tactic failed, motive is not type correct
  λ (_a : list α), l.last h1 = x = (_a.last h1 = x)
```

And the error message sheds more light into *why* it fails: The `rw` tactic takes the goal, which is

```
l.last h1 = x
```

finds the occurrences of the left-hand side of the equality, i.e. `l`, and then tries to equate the goal as we have it with the goal where `l` is replaced by a parameter `_a`. Adding one set of parenthesis clarifies things maybe a bit:

```
  λ (_a : list α), (l.last h1 = x) = (_a.last h1 = x)
```

Normally `rw` can use this function to turn the equality given to it (`hx`) into an equality between the existing goal and the goal you’d expect after the `rw`, but it doesn’t even get that far: The expression above is not type-correct! In `_a.last h1`, the `h1` is still `l ≠ nil`, but it now should be `_a ≠ nil`.

---

Unfortunately, `rw` is too limited to take care of this automatically. Work-arounds are, as you say

- use `simp_rw`, which is able to generalize goals even in these cases.

  But has it’s own shortcomings – you cannot rewrite with equalities like `l = head l @ tail l` that mention the LHS on the RHS. This is because `simp_rw` is based on simp, and as a *simplification* rule, this would be bad.
- use `simp only [hx] {single_pass := tt}`, which is similar to `simp_rw`, but doesn’t complain about such looping rewrites.
- If the equality has just a variable on one of its side (as it does here), then

  ```
  subst hx
  ```

  works nicely.
- If the dependent argument that gets in the way is a local hypothesis (such as the `hx` here), it can help to move it into the goal;

  ```
  revert h1, rw hx, intro h1,
  ```

  works here, and may work in your case. But it may not always be possible to revert all relevant hypotheses.
- If none of these help, you can try to extract a helper lemma where the thing you want to replace is a variable, use `subst` to prove that lemma quite directly, and then use that lemma.

Comment: `revert h1, rw hx` also works in this case :)

Comment: Is that a universally applicable workaround, or something that works sometimes?

Comment: Does `simp only [hx] {single_pass := tt}` avoid the shortcomings of `simp_rw hx`?

Comment: Ah, right, [you suggested that](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/pull/12520#discussion_r821557962). I’ll add it. What I find surprising: Why does `simp only` not complain about `hx` not being a suitable simplification lemma?

Comment: I couldn't find a good example of this, but I have also judiciously used `▸` for this; instead of the `rw`s as I usually would, I'd do `replace old_id : (exact_term_I_want) := h ▸old_id`; really tedious but it works well. For the goal, I guess you can use `change_to` in a similar way.